# ¿Cómo obtener el último registro por usuario en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla con registros de entradas y salidas por usuario, necesito obtener el último fichaje de cada usuario.

Esta es mi consulta, pero me devuelve ID_USUARIO repetidos y sólo quiero el último mas reciente.

```
SELECT c.ID, c.ID_USUARIO, c.FECHA, c.TIPO
FROM acceso c
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT MAX(FECHA) max_time
  FROM acceso
  GROUP BY Date(`FECHA`)
) AS t
ON c.FECHA = t.max_time
```

Mi tabla 'acceso':

```
ID   ID_USUARIO   FECHA                  TIPO
--   ----------   -------------------    ------
1    010          2020-07-05 15:20:01    ENTRADA
2    010          2020-07-05 18:25:00    SALIDA
3    066          2020-07-05 10:00:00    SALIDA
4    066          2020-07-05 12:00:00    ENTRADA
5    066          2020-07-05 18:00:00    SALIDA
6    011          2020-07-05 13:20:01    ENTRADA
7    011          2020-07-06 10:25:00    SALIDA
7    011          2020-07-06 11:25:00    ENTRADA
```

Quiero conseguir:

```
ID   ID_USUARIO   FECHA                  TIPO
--   ----------   -------------------    ------
2    010          2020-07-05 18:25:00    SALIDA
5    066          2020-07-05 18:00:00    SALIDA
7    011          2020-07-06 11:25:00    ENTRADA
```

SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/414960/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener la mayor de las fechas por cada usuario tienes que agrupar por `id_usuario`. Quedaría lo siguiente:

```
SELECT ID_USUARIO, MAX(FECHA) max_time
  FROM acceso
  GROUP BY ID_USUARIO
```

Lo que haces esa consulta es agrupar por los IDs de los usuarios de la tabla acceso y seleccionar la mayor de las fechas, lo cual equivale a la última.

Ahora, para evitar tener una misma fecha para dos usuarios establecen una segunda condición en el `JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.ID_USUARIO, c.FECHA, c.TIPO
FROM acceso c
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT ID_USUARIO, MAX(FECHA) max_time
  FROM acceso
  GROUP BY ID_USUARIO
) AS t
ON c.FECHA = t.max_time
AND c.ID_USUARIO=t.ID_USUARIO
```

Comment: Necesita seleccionar también el `ID_USUARIO` para poder hacer el `JOIN`.

Comment: Si? No lo veo realmente necesario, ya que la fecha sería suficiente para establecer el nexo entre los dos conjuntos de valores.

Comment: Dos usuarios distintos pueden tener un fichaje a la misma hora.

Comment: Cierto, tienes razón.

Comment: Hmm alguna condición falta.., con tu consulta el resultado de la columna TIPO siempre es "SALIDA", da la casualidad que en el ejemplo que te escribí, todos eran "SALIDA" pero cuando el último registro de un usuario es "ENTRADA", la consulta no la hace bien. He actualizado el ejemplo.

Comment: He dejado toda la información en fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/414960/2

Comment: Sólo tienes que añadir `ID_USUARIO` en el `SELECT` interior y cambiar el segundo `ON` por un `AND` para obtener los resultados esperados.

Comment: Fíjate en fiddle y la columna TIPO, no da los valores reales..(veo que muestra el TIPO del primer registro y la FECHA del último).

Comment: A mí sí me da los valores correctos.

Comment: @juanrpozo ¿has mirado el enlace de fiddle? No mires la columna de la fecha, fíjate en la de TIPO. El valor que aparece no es el que correspondería.

Comment: Sí: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/414960/5

Comment: Cierto! Estaba probando la primera consulta que propuso y no la segunda. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres únicamente mostrar los últimos registros por usuario cuando es "SALIDA", debes ejecutar esta consulta:

```
SELECT *,
       max(fecha) max_fecha
FROM acceso
GROUP BY id_usuario
```

De esta manera agrupas por id_usuario para que no se repitan y te filtra los últimos de SALIDA.

Comment: No quiero los que sean SALIDA, quiero que sea el último, sea SALIDA o ENTRADA pero muchas gracias por tu ayuda!